# Laravel : How can I change default indexing key length in morph table

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

I have table "invoice_relations" which is morph table.
So in migration I wrote :

$table->morphs('invoice_relations');

But it gives error while running migration as,

Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier na
  me 'invoice_relations_invoice_relations_id_invoice_relations_type_index' is too long in /var/www/html/st/sales-tantra/vendor/doctrine/dbal/
  lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:105

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your

```
$table->morphs('invoice_relations');
```

To this:

```
$table->morphs('invoice_relations', 'invoice_relations_morpf_key');
```

Or this:

```
    $table->unsignedInteger("invoice_relations_id");
    $table->string("invoice_relations_type");
    $table->index(["invoice_relations_id", "invoice_relations_type"], "YOUR_INDEX_NAME");
```

But I think name for polymorphic relations name ends 'able', for example relationable.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thanks J. Doe.                                                                                                      
$table->morphs('invoice_relations', 'invoice_relationable_morph_key'); is working for me.